# Sticky Footer Issues

Tags: css, footer, sticky

I am trying to create a sticky footer from a simple looking tutorial I found online. This seems to work ok until I try putting a width on my content div and I have no idea why.

If I add a width to the content div it seems the footer no longer has any distance between itself and the content div and so it obscures the content if there is a lot of content.

I have created this jsfiddle but it doesnt look as obvious there as it does if viewed in say firefix or IE.

Does anybody know why this is happening and what can I do to have a content div with a fixed width and auto margins to centre it but still have a footer that sticks to the bottom all the time if there is hardly any content or a large amount of content.

Below is my css for the content div:

```
#content {
                margin-top: 15px;                   
                padding-bottom:100px; /* Height of the footer element */
                border-left: 1px solid #C9C9C9;
                border-right: 1px solid #C9C9C9;
                border-bottom: 2px solid #C9C9C9;                    
                box-shadow: -3px 0 3px -3px #333, 3px 0 3px -3px #333;                    
                width: 1024px; /* Here adding a width causes the footer to overlap */
                margin-left:auto;
                margin-right:auto;
                background-color: white;
                text-align: center;
                border: 1px solid red;
            }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/32M9Q/1/

Comment: I view the fiddle with and without the width on content and it seems there is no difference with relations to the footer and content. Your footer is positioned absolutely so it's not a sticky footer to start with and it has nothing to do with your content width

Comment: Isn't it only a visual thing? Remove box shadow and borders from footer http://jsfiddle.net/32M9Q/7/

Comment: If its viewed as a web page I can see that when I remove the width on the content div then the footer is ok, it doesnt bleed over the content div obscuring the text, if I then add the width in it is now on top of the content div.

Answer (score 1):

At least in Chrome, the JSFiddle shows no problems for me. It looks the same with or without putting a width on content. I even added a bunch more words and the footer still didn't cut anything off. So the `padding` does effectively work, at least in my case.

However, based on what you said on the other answer, perhaps you could just change `position:absolute` on the footer to `position:relative` (assuming the footer won't have anything placed under it...and I'm guessing not since it's a footer). It makes sure the footer is placed after the content instead of being placed on it. Be wary, though, and make sure to check it in many different cases (browsers and devices).

I would also include a `margin-bottom` on the content, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following CSS rules to the #footer element:

```
position: fixed;
clear: both;
```

This will give you a sticky footer (if I got what you want to do correctly) that does not overlap with the main content. You can probably loose the clear: both part, but it may help with some browsers...

Comment: Hi sorry maybe my explanation was not really clear enough, I dont want a footer that is always at the bottom even if there is content, what I want is a footer that is always at the bottom of the page even if there is a lot of content, and if there is a lot of content I dont want the footer obscuring it.

Comment: @berimbolo why did you make the footer position absolute?

Comment: @Huangism I made the footer position absolute because thats the css from the tutorial and it does seem to work ok until there is a lot of content, at which point the footer bleeds over the content, until I remove the width from the content div.

Comment: In fact removing the width only means it no longer covers the text, the issue is that footer appears to be inside the content div even though it isnt. Its almost as if it isnt being pushed down but the padding-bottom.

Comment: @berimbolo the footer overlaps because your footer is positioned absolutely (takes it out of the normal flow). To have a footer that sits at the bottom when there is a lot of content then you don't need absolute however if you want a footer to sit at the bottom without content then you need absolute. Just add more padding to the content. You need to pad the height of the footer + the desired padding you wanted for the content, in your case, pad it 180px

Comment: @Huangism _ I think I follow but if you could amend the css sample in my answer and post that as I an answer if I can get it to work I can accept that as the answer.

Comment: @berimbolo my friend just change the `padding-bottom` on `#content` to `180px` You have 100 now which is the desired padding for the content, the extra 80 is for the footer since its height is 80

Comment: @Huangism - I had actually already tried this but as my footer and content are white backgrounds and my body background grey all I get is extra whitespace... maybe the answer is a hack to set a border top on my footer with the same colour as my background so I get the effect of space between the footer and the content.

Comment: @berimbolo so change the background color of body to white so it is seamless

Answer (score 0):

Setting the background color of my web page to match the footer and the body isnt an option, I appreciate all the answers I have been given so far but unfortunately none of them were suitable for me.

I have had to do what I consider to be a hack which is add a div below the content which is higher than the footer, this means the footer sits on top of this div and not my content giving the illusion of space between the content and the footer:

```
<div style="height: 120px;"></div>
<div id="footer"><span style="color: red"> This is the footer section</span></div>
```